# Vue 3 Compositions api not auto reloading when there's a changes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm currently taking a lesson in vue mastery. and there's a weird behavior. when I'm changing something in the App.vue it is auto reloading and showing my changes. But when I'm changing something in the component files, it is not auto reloading. i just follow the documentation on how to setup a vue 3 application

App.Vue

```
<script setup>
import ProductDisplay from '@/Components/ProductDisplay.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

 const cart = ref(0)
 const premium = ref(true)
</script>
<template>

<div class="nav-bar"></div>
<div class="cart">{{ cart }}</div>
<ProductDisplay :premium="premium" />

</template>
```

Components/ProductDisplay.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import socksGreen from "@/assets/images/socks_green.jpeg";
import socksBlue from "@/assets/images/socks_blue.jpeg";

const props = defineProps({
  premium: Boolean,
 });

 const details = ref(["50% cotton", "30% wool", "20% polyster"]);

 const variants = ref([
   { id: 2234, color: "green", image: socksGreen, quantity: 50 },
   { id: 2235, color: "blue", image: socksBlue, quantity: 0 },
 ]);

 const inStock = computed(() => {
   return variants.value[selectedVariants.value].quantity > 0;
 });
 const selectedVariants = ref(0);

 const cart = ref(0);

 const onClick = () => {
   cart.value += 1;
 };

 const image = computed(() => {
   return variants.value[selectedVariants.value].image;
 });
const updateVariant = (index) => {
  selectedVariants.value = index;
};

const shipping = computed(() => {
  if (props.premium) {
    return "Frees"
  } else {
    return "Out of Stock";
  }
});
</script>

<template>
 <div class="product-display">
   <div class="product-container">
     <div class="product-image">
       <img :src="image" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="product-info">
       <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
       <p v-if="inStock">In Stock</p>
       <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
       <p>{{ shipping }}</p>
       <ul>
         <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
       </ul>
      <div
        class="color-circle"
        v-for="(variant, i) in variants"
        :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.color }"
        @mouseover="updateVariant(i)"
      ></div>
      <button
        :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }"
        class="button"
        @click="onClick"
        :disabled="!inStock"
      >
        Add to Cart
      </button>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Save the changes?.

Comment: I'm saving it. but i needed to restart the server for the change to be visible in the component parts

Answer (score 0):

I've already resolve it. Just change the 'components' to 'Components'